# Does imaginary time actually not "generalize to curved space", or is it merely messy to generalize?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, topology, wick-rotation

I've run into the statement that imaginary time does not generalize to curved space, and other contradictory statements that imaginary time can be used with curved space but only awkwardly. Which is true?

Answer (score 2):

Trying to perform a Wick rotation will not work with non-static spacetimes, as can easily be seen with this rough argument :

Take a non-static spacetime, which has a metric of the form

$$ds^2 = -\alpha(t, x^i) dt^2 + \beta_i(t, x^i) dx^idt + \gamma_{ij}(t, x^i) dx^i dx^j$$

If we now perform the Wick rotation $t \to it$, we get the following metric

$$ds^2 = \alpha(it, x^i) dt^2 + i\beta_i(it, x^i) dx^idt + \gamma_{ij}(it, x^i) dx^i dx^j$$

This is not guaranteed to be a Riemannian manifold unless $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are independant of $t$ and $\beta = 0$, ie if the spacetime is static. The same argument works both way : Wick rotating a Lorentzian metric does not guarantee a Riemannian metric, nor does rotating a Euclidian metric guarantee a Lorentzian metric. You'll have to deal with a complex metric, for which there are some tricks but nothing quite as simple as Wick rotation in flat space.

Comment: In other words, it does not work to simply substitute *it* for *t*?  That makes sense, but I think it merely shows that the metric needs to be changed to accommodate the coordinate change.